# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4]

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to use Firebase on Android Studio
with the Firebase, I'm trying to use Realtime Database but after getting connecting the application to Firebase when i add Dependencies. 
I get an error in the build.grade app:

Uploading the codes

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vd14aak.Liftsafe"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error occours with `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using Gradle 3.4 or later, you won't be able to use `implementation` in your build.gradle to specify dependencies.  You can instead change that to `compile`, or you can upgrade your Gradle wrapper to something more recent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use at least [Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) and at least Gradle version 4.1 (which is Android plugin 3.0.0 requirement) to use [implementation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations).

And you also need to use the same version of firebase and play service. Don't use the following:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    ...
}
```

use the following:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    ...
}
```

Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses. Read more at At [Add Google Play Services to Your Project](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

And also, you need to use the same version of support library. Like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    ...
}
```